# How to set a backcolor of a control to a desired background control in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

My FORM is set to these properties:

```
FormBorderStyle = None;
BackColor = 64, 0 64;
Transparency Key = 64, 0 64;
```

Then, I put rectangleShape1, and a label1 into my form.

**rectangleShape1** property:

```
BackColor = SaddleBrown;
```

**label1** property :

```
BackColor = transparent;
```

I want the `label1.BackColor = transparent;` to be in rectangleShape1's BackColor, not in my FORM's BackColor. Is it possible? How do I do it? Thanks.

**Edit**

I want the backcolor of my label1 to be transparent because, I want to view the Backgroundimage of my rectangleShape1.

Comment: Just set a color: `label1.BackColor = SaddleBrown`. This will make the label brown, too.

Comment: But I want to use transparent. Not possible? Coz My `rectangleShape1` has BackgroundImage I want it to be shown. Not covered by the backcolor of label1.

Comment: Transparent is just a name that takes its beneath color as its own. At least that's how it is in Visual Studio. PMF answered you.

Comment: When I use `label1.BackColor = transparent;`, it just makes the `backcolor = 64, 0, 64`, which is the `transparency key` too.

Comment: Wait... Is `transparent` a variable of yours? If you really want it to be transparent, you have to set it as `Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: No its not a variable, im talking about its property.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete don't understand what your problem is, what's the relationship between your label and the rectangleShape? any overlapping? The `Transparent` in `winforms` means `transparent to the Parent`, it's not really transparent (as in `WPF`).

Comment: @KingKing, I added some info in my post.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete looks like you need this `label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent`

Comment: @KingKing it still goes into the backcolor of my form which is the same as my transparency key. I want it to be transparent but stick to the rectangleShape1's background color and so I can view the backgroundimage of the rectangleShape1 too..

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete OK, looks like I understand your problem, let me try it out, after trying it out, I'm sure that your `label1` has Parent as your form.

Comment: Nice. That's what I meant .. sorry I'm bad at explaining things.

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete but not really, your problem is still unclear. Could you try checking the `Parent` of your `label1` by this code `MessageBox.Show(label1.Parent.GetType().ToString());` I guess it would be `your form`, and if so you can't make it work as what you want. You have to set your label1's Parent to your rectangleShape

Comment: The parent is my form. how do I set my label1's parent to rectangleShape then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the BackColor of a control to `Color.Transparent` means that it uses its parent background.

Here are your options:

1. Assuming that rectangleShape1 is some kind of control you can make it the parent of your label:

   ```
   label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
   label1.Parent = rectangleShape1;
   ```

   This will however restrict the extent of the label to the rectangle.
2. Create your own [transparent label](http://www.doogal.co.uk/transparent.php).

Answer (score 0):

Transparent doesn't exist in Label and most control unless you actually overwrite the on_paint. Transparent just set the color of the parent container:

```
Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

=

```
Label1.BackColor = Label1.Parent.BackColor
```

Simply set the parent container to your rectangle assuming it's a container and your good to go. Otherwise you will need to derive some classes to make your rectangle container.

Edit:
If you want other flagrant evidence of similar behavior, then create a groupbox, add labels inside then change the font size, family and such and check the label changing by themselves. even thought fond is specified on them parent groupbox takes over. to prevent that behavior just put a panel in the group box and drag all label inside then do the same and you will see nothing happen.

There is few properties that behave like that and unfortunately figured this out along the years by fluke.

Comment: the `label1.Parent` may display some `picture`, that's why changing to the parent's BackColor would not work

Comment: then he can use the Graphics classes and use the drawtext function  to write directly on the picture.drawtext doesn't have background.